# How to clean confidential data in mercurial changesets?

Tags: mercurial, history, changeset

I want to sell a copy of my system and need to transfer the source code to my customers. I use Mercurial as the VCS. There are some confidential data in my code. For example, Amazon access key/secert key, database passwords and ssl private keys. Those keys are written in the code or configuration files, like this:

```
# settings of Amazon S3 storage
s3.storages:
    access_key: <secret>
    secret_key: <secret>
```

Before I transfer my code to them, I need to clean all those confidential data in the code base. But all of them are in history (changesets). With Mercurial, how can I clean those secret?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're giving the customers only a snapshot you can do it after you run `hg archive`.

If you want to give them access to the repository with full history you need to use `hg convert` to exclude that file.

In that case you're probably better off just invalidating the AWS key and using a new one in the future -- Amazon makes that very easy.

Going forward you're better off not putting those keys into source control.  Instead put in a `config.sample` file and then add `config.actual` top your `.hgignore`.